In classic Asp is it possible to change value to an unknown variable?
Don't know if title exactly fit what I need to know. I searched for an answer in Stackoverflow (and Internet too) without success (maybe I was not able to find it).
I have a web app written many years ago in classic ASP (vbscript). This app is multilingual and to do the things as simple as possible, I have written a big select case for each language. So I have almost 100 variables used all over the app, that contains the values for English, Italian, or French visitors.
Now I have to retrieve and change the value of no matter which variable with random content (maybe only one or all the variables) without knowing the name of the variable.
For example I have such situation

    select case strLangID
    
    case "en"
        MENU_PRODUCTS           = "Our Products"
        MENU_DIRECTORY          = "Directory"
        MENU_WHERE              = "Where We Are"
        MENU_WHO                = "About Us"
    case "fr"
        MENU_PRODUCTS           = "Nos produits"
        MENU_WHERE              = "Ou nous sommes"
        MENU_WHO                = "A propos de nous"
        MENU_DIRECTORY          = "Directory"
    case "it"
        MENU_PRODUCTS           = "I Nostri Prodotti"
        MENU_DIRECTORY          = "Directory"
        MENU_WHERE              = "Dove Siamo"
        MENU_WHO                = "Chi Siamo"
    end select


I have written a small program to test if it's possible to change the value of a random chosen variable on the fly, but I failed, so I ask to you if it's possible or it's me that I'm unable to:
dim aSiteDescr
dim intRnd
dim newString
dim newValue

' to hold the names of each variable
aSiteDescr = array( "MENU_PRODUCTS", "MENU_DIRECTORY", "MENU_WHERE", "MENU_WHO" )
randomize
intRnd = (int(rnd() * ubound(aSiteDescr)))
newString = aSiteDescr(intRnd)
response.write("newString " & newString & "<br>")
' returns "MENU_PRODUCTS" or correctly another item in aSiteDescr 

' and for example I tried to change the value of the var this way
newValue = Replace(Eval(newString), "Products", "x") 
response.write("newValue " & newValue & "<br>")
' returns "Our x" if newString is "MENU_PRODUCTS", 
  while leaving unchanged the other values corresponding to the other items in 
  aSiteDescr array

Now I want to update the original variable randomly choosen with the new value in newValue. I've tried newString = newValue but, obviously the value of the original variable is unchanged. Please note that I do not know the name of the variable that is to be updated with the new value, so I cant' write MENU_PRODUCTS = newValue
In other languages this macrosubstitution it's fairly simple I would like to know if it is possible in vbscript
Thank you all, Marco

Wouldn’t ExecuteGlobal newString & " = newValue" work? Which is same as MENU_PRODUCTS = newValue in effect you are executing using the output of newString which is the randomly selected variable name you wish to update the value of.

@user692942, thank you. I'm pretty sure to have already tested this solution, but I do not remember, sincerely, because I've tried many different solutions and noone worked before. I will try and will report here the results. I'm sure to have not used executeglobal but only Execute

The difference between Execute and ExecuteGlobal is scope, ExecuteGlobal executes the string as script in the global script scope. This is important in Classic ASP because of how code is often structured in Classic ASP pages.

@user692942 yesss it works! I repeat I was sure to have already used your suggestion because I had found it in the Internet and on Stackoverflow but It gave me an error: the program ended without any message, and I was wonder what was the cause..... A silly mistake: I was writing newvValue instead of newValue (adding a v before Value). I corrected my errortyping and all worked. Sorry for the noise, and thank you all!

BTW it works both with Execute and ExecuteGlobal

Like I said it would depend on how your code is structured but I tend to use ExecuteGlobal to avoid any scoping issues.

The "rnd" function always generates a random number between 0 and 1 but always less than 1. Therefore the final number of your variable will never be 3 (which is the last item in your array).
To get the result you want you need to change the following line:
newValue = Replace(Eval(newString), "Products", "x")

To:
newValue = Replace(newString, "PRODUCTS", "x")

I tested it here and it worked perfectly.

But that doesn't assign the value to the variable they want it assigned to. Read the comments before posting.

Thank you for your interest in my question, but it is not the correct answer. As I wrote before I had the solution but It was my fault to misspelling one variable name. Once I've corrected the error and re-inserted the instruction suggested by @user692942, all it worked
